# activerecord-userstamp gem is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubygems

I trying to update rails 3.x to 4.2.x.And I am trying to replace userstamp gem with activerecord-userstamp to store  creator and updater ids.

I followed all steps provided by activerecord-userstamp gem in github and configured gem properly

```
   ActiveRecord::Userstamp.configure do |config|
     # config.default_stamper = 'User'
     # config.creator_attribute = :creator_id
     # config.updater_attribute = :updater_id
     config.deleter_attribute = nil
   end
```

After I reset database and did migrations

but still my schema has not updated to creator_id,updater_id

```
      t.integer  "created_by", limit: 4
      t.integer  "updated_by", limit: 4
```

In my model user.rb

```
     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      model_stamper
     end
```

in my collections.rb

```
      class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
       stampable
      end
```

When I try to store the creator_id and updated id it not storing to database

```
| created_id | updated_id |
+----+--------+-----------+-
|  NULL      |       NULL |
```

Can any one help with your solutions

Answer (score 0):

Activerecord-userstamp failed to load MigrationHelper while I am running migrations. I resolved this issue by Adding migration helper to my repo and make use of this helper method in my migration file.

helper/activerecorduserstamp.rb

```
module activeRecorduserstamp

  module ActiveRecord::Userstamp::MigrationHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   def userstamps(*args)
      config = ActiveRecord::Userstamp.config
      column(config.creator_attribute, :integer, *args)
      column(config.updater_attribute, :integer, *args)
      column(config.deleter_attribute, :integer, *args) if config.deleter_attribute.present?
   end
 end

  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition.class_eval do
    include ActiveRecord::Userstamp::MigrationHelper
  end
end
```

In My migrations file I included that helper method as

db/migration/yyy.rd

```
include activeRecorduserstamp
class YYY < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      change_table :YYY do |t|
      t.userstamps
    end
```

After adding helper method to my migration file .Activerecord-Userstamp working great.

Refer [github issue](https://github.com/lowjoel/activerecord-userstamp/issues/15)